# *responsive* SVG graphic with paint fill

Tags: svg

Is it possible to create a *scalable* SVG graphic like this ?
[Scalable SVG graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7aOG.png)
I want it to resize according to the device dimensions. I'm trying to create a background image which'll use the full page dimensions - not fixed layout.

This is what I've come up with so far.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <title>New Design</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, div, span
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;    
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }    
    body
    {
        font-family:'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;    
        background-color:lightyellow;
    }
    html
    {
        height:100%;
    }
    body
    {
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    #container
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color:#eceff1;
        position:absolute; 
        top:0; 
        left:0;
        right:0; 
        bottom:0;    
    }
    path {
        fill: blue;
    }​
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div style="width:calc(100% - 100px);height:calc(100% - 100px);margin:0 auto;padding:10px;border:1px solid red;">
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #5A07BC;background-color:#fff">
          <line x1="20%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="200" style="stroke:#5A07BC;stroke-width:1" />
          <line x1="50%" y1="200" x2="0" y2="450" style="stroke:#5A07BC;stroke-width:1" />            
          
          <line x1="100%" y1="20%" x2="60%" y2="60%" style="stroke:#2AA4C6;stroke-width:1" />
          <line x1="60%" y1="60%" x2="95%" y2="100%" style="stroke:#2AA4C6;stroke-width:1" />                  
        
    </div>
        
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not required to have every element in your SVG be in percentages. SVG graphics are scalable by default, but you need to include a [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute that describes its coordinate system.

The `viewBox` attribute takes four values — `viewBox="x_min y_min width height"` — which describe the extent of the drawing inside the SVG. You'll usually have something like `viewBox='0 0 800 600'` which means *I have drawn things on a canvas of 800x600 "pixels", with the origin at x = 0, y = 0*.

Then when you set a particular `width` and `height` to a SVG, it will, by default, *stretch* the image to fit these dimensions, but you can control the behavior with the [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute.

**Further reading:** There's a [good article on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) about these two properties.